# Convert Text in textbox into a shape (component or javascript)

Tags: html, css

On `stackoverflow.com` when you enter the tags for your question you can hit the space button and it gets a blue box around it with an X. I want to use that in my website how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try out [this](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2011/09/09/Tag-Editor-Field-using-jQuery-similar-to-StackOverflow.aspx) custom JQuery Pluggin